# Having issues creating an Upscale Code that accepts and Scaling Factor (Scaling factor 2 = scale by half)

Tags: simulation, numerical-methods

I'm writing an upscaling code which numerically upscales values from their original source by any factor possible and am getting issues, I have a working code for a scale factor of 4 but cant seem to get it to work for other values:

Working for SCX=4
%Kx Upscaling
for i = 1:Nx/kx_scaling
for j=1:Ny/kx_scaling

```
I=kx_scaling*i-1;
J=kx_scaling*j-1;
```

%     ko(i,j) = [K(I,J),K(I+1,J),K(I,J+1),K(I+1,J+1)]
Q1(i,j) = - K(I+1,J)*dy*(Pbot-P_matrix(I+1,J))/mu/(dx/2);

```
end
```

end

for i = 1:Nx/kx_scaling
for j=1:Ny/kx_scaling

```
I=kx_scaling*i-1;
J=kx_scaling*j-1;
```

Q2(i,j) = - K(I+1,J)*dy*(Pbot-P_matrix(I+1,J))/mu/(dx/2);

```
end
```

end
Q = Q1+Q2;

Knumeric = - Q*mu*2*dx/(2*dz)/(Pbot-Pinit);
Kx_3D(:, :, layer-34) = Knumeric;

This is the current non working code:
for i = 1:scaled_Nx
for j=1:scaled_Ny

```
    I = min(SCX * (i-1), Nx-1);
    J = min(SCX * (j-1), Ny-1);
    
    Q1(i,j) = - K(I+1, J+1) * dy * (Pbot - P_matrix(I+1, J+1)) / mu / (dx/2);
end
```

end

for i = 1:scaled_Nx
for j=1:scaled_Ny

```
    I = min(SCX * (i-1), Nx-1);
    J = min(SCX * (j-1), Ny-1);

    Q2(i,j) = - K(I+1, J+1) * dy * (Pbot - P_matrix(I+1, J+1)) / mu / (dx/2);
end
```

end
Q = Q1 + Q2;
Knumeric = (Q.*mu)./((Pbot-P_matrix).*dy);

Kx_3D(:, :, layer-34) = Knumeric;

i tried adding a user inputted scaling factor, rounding it so that it would work, but I cant get the left and right hand sides to match.